# :first in ie6 and ie7

Tags: jquery, rel

I want to know that would this function will work in ie 6, I currently can have ie6 on my machine

```
$(function(){
  $('#slides-thumbs li:first a').each(function(){

    $(this).removeAttr('rel');

    })
})
```

My concern is :first

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work with no problems. jQuery is designed to work cross-browser, and IE6 is no exception.

Many of the selectors you can use with jQuery are borrowed from CSS3, so if you were to use them in your CSS, IE6 would then have problems. However, `:first` is a jQuery extension and not part of CSS so that's not totally relevant here.

For example, the `:first-child` CSS selector will not work in IE6, but will work perfectly fine when used as part of a jQuery selector, even in IE6.